# How do i take input from a usb keyboard to arduino uno

Tags: keyboard, arduino, usb, arduino-uno

I am trying to do USB keyboard interfacing with arduino UNO. I would like to take input in the form of ascii values. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answering my question. But i figured it out that we could use a female USB connector and connect the data pins with the pwm pins and further use the PS2Keyboard.h library to read input.

Answer (score -2):

The newer 32u4-based Arduino boards (such as Leonardo) support a [native Mouse and/or Keyboard](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/MouseKeyboard) integration. For the Arduino Uno you will need extra libraries/firmware to realize a HID keyboard. You can find several approaches and libraries on the web (e.g. [Arduino HID Project 2.2](https://github.com/NicoHood/HID), [Turning an Arduino into a USB keyboard](http://hackaday.com/2012/06/29/turning-an-arduino-into-a-usb-keyboard/) and so on. Search "Arduino Uno as HID keyboard").